# Is there proper way to concatenate a base path name with a new path name?

Tags: c

Is there a way where you can update the char arrays of a base path with an updated path?

```
struct dirent *dp;
DIR *dir;
struct stat buf;
dir = opendir("./statdir/");
int x;
char base_path[11] = "./statdir/";
char* full_path;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  while((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
     full_path = strcat(base_path, dp->d_name);

     if((x = lstat(full_path, &buf)) == -1) {
         perror("stat failed");
         exit(1);
       }
       printf("Debug: %s\n", full_path);

     }
     closedir(dir);
     return(0);
  }
}
```

My goal is to update full_path after each loop to the base_path + whatever argument is passed to argv[] and in my directory i have two files name file1 and file2....

i.e if I ran my code and wrote ./Stat, I expected full_path to be "./statdir/file1" and then "./statdir/file2"

The results I am getting however is :

Debug: ./statdir/.

Debug: ./statdir/...

stat failed: No such file or directory

Comment: `dir = opendir("./statdir/");` you have that in file scope???

Comment: Put the debug `printf()` *before* you `exit()`...

Comment: Are you sure this code compiles?

Comment: Also, `full_path = strcat(base_path, dp->d_name);` will cause `base_path` to grow and grow and grow with each loop iteration.

Comment: `base_path` should be big enough to hold the concatenated string. For you that's not the case

Comment: Is there a way to reset the full_path to base_path after calling lstat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're concatenating a string onto `base_path`, however that array is just long enough for what you initialized with.  That means you're writing past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also note that `full_path` is pointing to the start of `base_path`.

Instead, make `full_path` an array big enough to hold a full path.  Then use `strcpy` to copy over the base path, then `strcat` to add on the current entry.

```
char full_path[100];
...

  while((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    strcpy(full_path, base_path);
    strcat(full_path, dp->d_name);
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue. =]

Answer (score 1):

You could build the full filename using `snprintf` like this...

```
snprintf(full_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s",base_path, dp->d_name);
```

...but you'll first need to ensure that `full_path` has the space to contain the filename so replace

```
char *full_path;
```

with

```
char full_path[PATH_MAX];
```

Comment: `snprintf()` would be much better.